# C# Regex.Matches returns too many matches?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

Can someone explain to me why the result from the following statement has a count of two an not just one?

```
MatchCollection matches = new Regex( ".*" ).Matches( "foo" ) ;
Assert.AreEqual( 1, matches.Count ) ; // will fail!

new Regex( ".+" ).Matches( "foo" ) ; // returns one match (as expected)
new Regex( ".*" ).Matches( "" ) ; // also returns one match
```

(I'm using C# of .NET 3.5)

Comment: Have you looked at the matches to see what they are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `"*."` matches `"foo"` at the start of the string, and an empty string at the end (position 3).  Remember, `*` means, "zero or more".  So it matches "nothing" at the end of the string.

This is consistent.  `Regex.Match(string.Empty, ".*");` returns one match:  an empty string.

Comment: But the * is greedy, so I assumed there is nothing left to match (not even an empty string) after the first match. I could also argue that there are an infinite number of empty strings at the end of the input not just one. In either case, I'm puzzled an I have to re-write some of my Unit tests to reflect this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Include '^' to anchor your matching expression at the start of the input string.

```
MatchCollection matches = new Regex( "^.*" ).Matches( "foo" ) ;
```

Comment: This is a workaround, but I still don't understand, why the original .* Regex leads to two matches

Comment: I guess I should have clarified your intent.  What are you trying to do?